# Passing a query parameters in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, feathersjs

I queried the data from the database by the passed parameters for example

```
http://localhost:3030/people?$skip=0&$limit=25&$sort[name]=0&description[$name]=rajiv
```

But I wanted to add an extra param but I don't want to use it or include it in a query , cause it will cause error , I just wanted to pass that to get the key and value. Supposed I want to add param table=people and the url would be

```
  http://localhost:3030/people?$skip=0&$limit=25&$sort[name]=0&description[$name]=rajiv&table=people
```

But adding the table=people param would cause an error cause it was included in the query and I dont want to include it , I just want to pass it for a purpose.

> **#error**  "message": "Unknown column 'table.people' in 'where clause'",

Can I pass a param in the url and not include it on a query ? Thanks.

Comment: are you not in control of the backend server parsing the url?

Comment: you want to pass it but do not want to pass it?  I am confused here; perhaps you can define "for a purpose"

Comment: I want to pass it but I dont want to include it in the query . I wanted to get that key and value in the back-end

Comment: @henokg i am using feathers js

Comment: What is it used for if not for the query? Question is very vague

Comment: I am using it for a targe column like const targetColumn = 'table.people'; for example

Comment: @charlietfl I wanted to pass to param to the back-end because I have some purpose for it Sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only want to pass the key,value pair to backend without including it in the url then what you can do is add it on the request header. here is more info
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Setting_HTTP_request_headers